# Movement training

Tags: calisthenics

When training for a specific movement in calisthenics, such as planche or front lever, should I be training for both movements at the same time or should I focus on one single movement?

Answer (score 1):

Both.

They're both different movements that use a conjunction or muscles for each. Your body will learn to adapt to both just as quick as if you were to do one at a time. Its all about strength, control and balance. All can be improved by doing both exercises.